# Removing rows based on words contained in multiple columns

Tags: python, loops, csv, dataframe, delete-row

I'm still having trouble getting the right output on my data. I am looking at a dataframe imported from .csv - I want to iterate over 3 columns and remove any rows that 'contain' any of the following list - `['testing-dashboard','cdn.openfin.co','localhost', '_qa','-qa', 'uat.', 'uat-', 'staging.','test','developer','_uat_','-UAT']`

When I use the below script and compare it by manually removing the data in excel - I do not get the same numbers. Any idea why it is not working properly?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

raw_data = pd.read_csv('No License Key.csv', delimiter = ',', keep_default_na=False, low_memory=False)

selected_raw_data = raw_data[['App Config', 'App Name', 'App UUID', 'Machine ID', 'Estimated Company']].reset_index()

remove_from_data =  '|'.join(['testing-dashboard','cdn.openfin.co','localhost', '_qa','-qa', 'uat.', 'uat-', 'staging.','test','developer','_uat_','-UAT'])
#print(remove_from_data)
data_output = selected_raw_data

for item in ['App Config', 'App Name', 'App UUID']:
    data_output = data_output[~data_output[item].str.contains(remove_from_data, case= False)]
    data_output.reset_index()

#print(len(data_output))

unique_desktops = data_output['Machine ID'].nunique()

print(unique_desktops)
```

Comment: Hi, when I tried your code with my dummy data, I saw that it worked on basic inputs - can you post the output you expected and the output you received. Maybe double check the remove_from_data (note that it removes any occurrence of items in the list, even if they occur in the middle) and to clarify that you will remove the full row if any one of the remove_from_data words items is contained in any of the three columns you've chosen. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the cause of the difference between the results. The list is removing any row containing 'dev' even though I specify ' dev' (note the space before dev in the second example. Is there a way around this??